# Why my devices does not give me a full internet speed

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, wifi-configuration, internet-speed, speedtest

I am wondering for some questions on my mind related to internet speed compared on my many different devices. I have 5G internet on my home, and according to the internet provider, the speed that I should get is between 200 Mbps to 1 Gbps.

- When I connect my router to my phone (Samsung galaxy S20+ 5G) which has the following Wi-Fi capabilities (Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac/ax) my speedtest.net result varies from 400 Mbps to 600 Mbps which seems normal.
- When I connect the same router to my desktop computer using Cat6 Ethernet cable with speed of 1 Gbps, the speed test result is not reaching above 200 Mbps while the network connection speed is 1Gbps.
- When I connect the same router to my (Samsung Note 9 ) which has the following Wi-Fi capabilities (Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac), the speed also is not reaching above (150 MBps) and according to internet the Wi-Fi ac band suppose to be capable to handle speed at least 1200 Mbps.

I have a plan to purchase a new apple mac mini which has a Wi-Fi standards (802.11ac Wi-Fi wireless networking IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n compatible).

I am wondering whether I will get my 5G speed on the Mac mini or not.

Comment: Speed test apps often don't compare with the same methods. I'd suggest you measure the download of the same large file from the same source to obtain a more objective measurement.

Comment: @K7AAY I did test with two device, both devices has been tested with 976.56 MB file  (Samsung S20+ - speedtest.net -> 380 Mbps - time taken to download 00m:20s) - (Samsung note 9 - speedtest.net -> 161 Mbps - time taken to download 01m:06s)  i think the speedtest.net app is giving the right speed indicator according to the download time compared between both devices